# Type '{ status: boolean; image: null; price: number; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'SelectedCustomImageType'

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, next.js

I am working on the Next js 14 TS app and got this error:

```
Type '{ status: boolean; image: null; price: number; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'SelectedCustomImageType': status, image, pricets(2739)
(property) selectedCustomImage: SelectedCustomImageType
```

Error Image :
[image]

this is my code :

```
    "use client";
    import { useCart } from "@/hooks/useCart";
    import { customImage } from "@/utils/customImage";
    import { formatPrice } from "@/utils/formatprice";
    import { Rating } from "@mui/material";
    import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
    import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { MdCheckCircle } from "react-icons/md";
    import toast from "react-hot-toast";
    import Button from "@/app/components/Button";
    import CustomImageInput from "@/app/components/inputs/CustomImageInput";
    import PackageButton from "@/app/components/inputs/PackageButton";
    import ProductImage from "@/app/components/products/ProductImage";
    import SetQuantity from "@/app/components/products/SetQuantity";
    import TypeImage from "@/app/components/products/TypeImage";
    import SetColor from "@/app/components/products/setColor";
    import SetType from "@/app/components/products/setType";
    
    interface ProductDetailsProps {
      product: any;
    }
    
    export type CartProductType = {
      id: string;
      name: string;
      description: string;
      category: string;
      brand: string;
      selectedImg: SelectedImgType;
      selectedProduct: SelectedProductType;
      quantity: number;
      selectedPackage: SelectedPackageType;
      price: number;
      productPrice: number;
      file: any;
      selectedCustomImage: SelectedCustomImageType;
    };
    // customImagePrice: number;
    
    export type SelectedImgType = {
      color: string;
      colorCode: string;
      image: string;
    };
    
    export type SelectedProductType = {
      type: string;
      typeCode: string;
      typePrice: number;
      image: string;
    };
    
    export type SelectedPackageType = {
      packaging: string;
      price: number;
      image: string;
    };
    
    export type SelectedCustomImageType = {
      status: boolean;
      image: string;
      price: number;
    };
    
    export type CustomImage = {
      status: boolean;
      image: File | null;
      price: number;
    };
    
    const Horizontal = () => {
      return <hr className="w-[30% my-2]" />;
    };
    
    const ProductDetails: React.FC<ProductDetailsProps> = ({ product }) => {
      const router = useRouter();
    
      const { handleAddProductToCart, cartProducts } = useCart();
    
      const [isProductInCart, setIsProductInCart] = useState(false);
    
      const [cartProduct, setCartProduct] = useState<CartProductType>({
        id: product.id,
        name: product.name,
        description: product.description,
        category: product.category,
        brand: product.brand,
        selectedImg: { ...product.images[0] },
        selectedProduct: { ...product.type[0] },
        quantity: 1,
        price: product.price,
        productPrice: product.price,
        selectedPackage: { ...product.productPackages[0] },
        file: null,
        selectedCustomImage: customImage,
      });
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setIsProductInCart(false);
    
        if (cartProducts) {
          const existingIndex = cartProducts.findIndex(
            (item) => item.id === product.id
          );
    
          if (existingIndex > -1) {
            setIsProductInCart(true);
          }
        }
      }, [cartProducts]);
    
      const productrating =
        product.reviews.reduce((acc: number, item: any) => item.rating + acc, 0) /
        product.reviews.length;
    
      const handleColorSelect = useCallback(
        (value: SelectedImgType) => {
          setCartProduct((prev) => {
            return { ...prev, selectedImg: value };
          });
        },
        [cartProduct.selectedImg]
      );
      const handleCustomImageSelect = useCallback(
        (value: SelectedProductType) => {
          setCartProduct((prev) => {
            if ((cartProduct.file = null)) {
            }
            return {
              ...prev,
              selectedProduct: value,
              price: product.price,
              productPrice: value.typePrice * cartProduct.quantity,
              customImagePrice: value.typePrice * cartProduct.quantity,
            };
          });
        },
        [cartProduct.selectedProduct]
      );
      const handleTypeSelect = useCallback(
        (value: SelectedProductType) => {
          setCartProduct((prev) => {
            return {
              ...prev,
              selectedProduct: value,
              price: product.price,
              productPrice: value.typePrice * cartProduct.quantity,
              customImagePrice: value.typePrice * cartProduct.quantity,
            };
          });
        },
        [cartProduct.selectedProduct]
      );
    
      const handlePackageSelect = useCallback(
        (value: SelectedPackage) => {
          setCartProduct((prev) => {
            return {
              ...prev,
              selectedPackage: value,
              price: product.price,
              productPrice: value.price * cartProduct.quantity,
              customImagePrice: value.price * cartProduct.quantity,
            };
          });
        },
        [cartProduct.selectedProduct]
      );
    
      const handleQtyIncrease = useCallback(() => {
        if (cartProduct.quantity === 99) {
          return;
        }
    
        setCartProduct((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, quantity: ++prev.quantity };
        });
      }, [cartProduct]);
    
      const handleQtyDecrease = useCallback(() => {
        if (cartProduct.quantity === 1) {
          return;
        }
    
        setCartProduct((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, quantity: --prev.quantity };
        });
      }, [cartProduct]);
      //console.log("this is cart product >>>>", cartProduct);
    
      const [images, setImages] = useState<CustomImage[] | null>();
    
      const addImageToState = useCallback((value: CustomImage) => {
        setImages((prev) => {
          if (!prev) {
            return [value];
          }
          return [...prev, value];
        });
      }, []);
    
      const removeImageFromState = useCallback((value: CustomImage) => {
        setImages((prev) => {
          if (prev) {
            const filteredImages = prev.filter((item) => item.price != value.price);
            return filteredImages;
          }
          return prev;
        });
      }, []);
    
      const [isProductCreated, setIsProductCreated] = useState(false);
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            {" "}
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-12">
              <ProductImage
                cartProduct={cartProduct}
                product={product}
                handleColorSelect={handleColorSelect}
              />
              <div className="flex flex-col gap-1 text-slate-700 text-sm">
                <h2 className="text-3xl font-medium text-slate-700">
                  {product.name}
                </h2>
                <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                  <Rating value={productrating} readOnly />
                  <div>{product.reviews.length} reviews</div>
                </div>
                <Horizontal />
                <div className="text-justify">{product.description}</div>
                <Horizontal />
                <div>
                  <span className="font-semibold">CATEGORY : </span>
                  {product.category}
                </div>
                <div>
                  <span className="font-semibold">BRAND : </span>
                  {product.brand}
                </div>
                <div
                  className={
                    product.availablequantity > 0
                      ? "text-teal-400"
                      : "text-rose-400"
                  }
                >
                  {product.availablequantity > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock"}
                </div>
                <Horizontal />
                {isProductInCart ? (
                  <>
                    <p className="mb-2 text-slate-500 flex items-center gap-1">
                      <MdCheckCircle className="text-teal-400" size={20} />
                      <span>Product added to Cart</span>
                    </p>
                    <div className="max-w-[300px]">
                      <Button
                        label="View Cart"
                        outline
                        onClick={() => {
                          router.push("/cart");
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <div>
                      <span className="font-semibold">TYPE : </span>
                      <TypeImage
                        cartProduct={cartProduct}
                        product={product}
                        handleTypeSelect={handleTypeSelect}
                      />
                      <SetType
                        cartProduct={cartProduct}
                        type={product.type}
                        handleTypeSelect={handleTypeSelect}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <Horizontal />
                    <SetColor
                      cartProduct={cartProduct}
                      images={product.images}
                      handleColorSelect={handleColorSelect}
                    />
                    <Horizontal />
                    <SetQuantity
                      cartProduct={cartProduct}
                      handleQtyIncrease={handleQtyIncrease}
                      handleQtyDecrease={handleQtyDecrease}
                    />
                    <Horizontal />
                    <div>
                      <div className="justify-self-end font-semibold">
                        <span className="font-semibold">PRICE : </span>
                        {formatPrice(product.price)}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <Horizontal />
                    <div>
                      <div className="justify-self-end font-semibold">
                        <span className="font-semibold">Packaging : </span>
                        {/** Add packaging type here grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 max-w-[300px] mt-6 mb-6*/}
                      </div>
                      <div className="">
                        <PackageButton
                          handlePackageSelect={handlePackageSelect}
                          cartProduct={cartProduct}
                          product={product}
                          label={product.productPackages}
                          price={[]}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <Horizontal />
                    <div>
                      <div className="justify-self-end">
                        <span className="font-semibold">Custom Image : </span>
                        <div className="w-full flex flex-col flex-wrap gap-4">
                          <div>
                            <div className="font-bold subpixel-antialiased">
                              Add your company logo, name or any other custom image
                              which should be printed on your product.
                            </div>
                            <div className="text-sm italic mt-1">
                              Additional charges apply!
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-3">
                            {customImage.map((item, index) => {
                              return (
                                <CustomImageInput
                                  key={index}
                                  item={item}
                                  addImageToState={addImageToState}
                                  removeImageFromState={removeImageFromState}
                                  isProductCreated={isProductCreated}
                                  cartProduct={cartProduct}
                                  setCartProduct={setCartProduct}
                                  handleCustomImageSelect={handleCustomImageSelect}
                                />
                              );
                            })}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div>{/* add image upload here */}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div className="justify-self-end font-semibold">
                        <span className="font-semibold">Total: </span>
                        {/* {cartProduct.isCustomImage
                          ? formatPrice(
                              cartProduct.productPrice * cartProduct.quantity +
                                cartProduct.selectedPackage.price *
                                  cartProduct.quantity
                            )
                          : formatPrice(
                              cartProduct.productPrice * cartProduct.quantity +
                                cartProduct.selectedPackage.price *
                                  cartProduct.quantity +
                                cartProduct.customImagePrice
                            )} */}
                        {/* {formatPrice(
                          cartProduct.productPrice * cartProduct.quantity + cartProduct.selectedPackage.price *cartProduct.quantity)} */}
                        {formatPrice(
                          (cartProduct.productPrice =
                            (cartProduct.price +
                              cartProduct.selectedProduct.typePrice +
                              cartProduct.selectedPackage.price) *
                            cartProduct.quantity)
                        )}
    
                        <span className="font-semibold">
                          Type: {cartProduct.selectedProduct.typePrice}
                        </span>
                        <span className="font-semibold">
                          Package: {cartProduct.selectedPackage.price}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="max-w-[300px] ">
                      <Button
                        label="Add To Cart"
                        onClick={() => handleAddProductToCart(cartProduct)}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default ProductDetails;
```

this is my import :

```
export const customImage = [
  {
    status: false,
    image: null,
    price: 10,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

> Type '{ status: boolean; image: null; price: number; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'SelectedCustomImageType': status, image, pricets(2739) (property) selectedCustomImage: SelectedCustomImageType

If you read that carefully...

> Type '{ status: boolean; image: null; price: number; }[]'

Note the `[]` at the end. That means that type is an array.

> is missing the following properties from type 'SelectedCustomImageType': status, image, pricets

An array does not have the expected properties, so you get a type error.

---

It seems like you expect `customImage` to be an object type, and not an array type.

So remove the array:

```
export const customImage = {
  status: false,
  image: null,
  price: 10,
},
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-SK64E-UhKAyusbu-3e9XEmB8gOrD1HEGJ8Kl2Px1MRnylh3CunOpM6stpjOGExu0tegmsnlIIuB8JgHknBPPOCCx1wEUt8LJ9sRztZqi9vOEg32W1t4erPwwQJ-CBR1CWVsc2sVzrSufNsXpzPd7O97dGtzFoM+Q-HziniE+kvFMADFFTgAAfe8OHFO950fVcLGseAAAloGAAAvKw5DYYsAAoAEoAwAPlWIgjygSw4AAHgACygK02BQBgGAAOQOJB3A0AB3ABaABtABmTIAFI4BAfpeIAJgAXQ0OAzWI01DCQmw4ALOoGiaIJkB0AA6EDmGojT6hQRpmhwNpSM8PDaCSONumUIj3FI78rSsNScDoQpiykBAIG8xlCMzF4PPgWhaMBCEAEEKiJCVCwgGYYAEV5ZgS9oVE8KRkuCwxQuQuB+OACyHIwBxLGSgQmBgBxSvmWrKpQWAZN8phZDePDiiaJACJC9zCv4tKYALar6mSgtWuy9q5AUaiJoSvliNs8IfGAIF7IavT1oSHw5w4oJNu6PT9kOXafHOS5rlue5pwSvTLquYAbjuSxzqtN4PigL47rKmA9NeBQvv6d7-kBQ77rBywKnetVCRhIJaD05Gjowba2wYfjMlapRYf7HEEsRuBkb01H-tLLGcfeikqWAGkMnemc0jJ0nklSRmEsbCG-tZoU8Z9Nk0B4K8kZR+6ycF4W3Ex7HlHehUIVpeJVt8fGNRtO0U2tQ1dyiAQLRo3jeNUfIkHCJQ+vywQkBEMQMDwwiSNWH96jqgsKty7qmEtlXgEwOA8OGgsGCIty9oGtSTBK25tgq85jGLIOMr0hVobjkw8JV8O8LppAQGc0jc5AbaKgDdxPBZ9as7gH3w7W-28KjmwTnThPSN49JQ+rl3avq7oPeamA8MeOhet+cPcgn82BCGwfg5k2uI-gMmARjlwAxVlmiAAN2AJBuIYPSiHmJAHfQNAnUZAQi96AYC4iBRi9Xk44AAajgc+BEyIizU3+6d73gfPSEJtgwFov1VS8BIrQwhLGaMm54DTRYOwLgvBM7Z23uwUeep4aoj5PfMOe0aoLT+g7JISBt4EO7nAcidBKI0GJmLChY0fQIzgJgtgo9lDjz2hbHhuMVaz3SjzOGUIYQyXCJbAqaloEVFgRrNsCC2rII4NwIW6C9p4Q4dgvsAtFrLCoXXVWMASENTITvQxRiIgN0DnPe6CsVixA4ARLuVjlDUNofQwhRiSbkO3u9IxoiCZ-SCNopAAS65M25ltJmETw4SzZmkMJekGyJLgAAKg+sIraNMCh0xBtQl4Cj7SJNCVgpAKTliNgyVkka91cnUgKW4zsRi+EqwEeHIRdSRFq0mpI34kC4CyIhHyJRSDWCqLQSrLR5ScGsn0VMSx4diF2NIXhPxSy66eKot4uuvid5xKIb0wm7DymHNvLOFmsTCm-QalzU5nCKmpKFDUpOPMGn5POVaYpbh7nJOeakV5qycmUjyRMQ5LS65tInu9LpBY9JBPin9CRPhF6DOGUgSWUQxnWwmag9R0ywlzO5ELKImye6mO6OYih5K9rbOdlY-ZzCbmIqxSmMJXyom3OOtctxnQ-p-PKbzQFmS3kgtpuCm52sdya0xaUh5o9hWKFFcC46HzJXNJ4T4aFvDYViuOqyhKKKa4QLCkMqKSAACKEwKpXFQEwZReK1E8Adpsv2Ad9Vo3Vf0MungACcfrXFbPqHQi87SrYUtVfbdZFina7PpaLVmzC4DeqCK-V+fi9Leu4e0qRcsiqepgAvU1hUMXWv6HUO1zEVg5RQc611cbfYN0LVm0FjTfUZCDeHbZ-CI3GMpdGjZjajEJsYUm-xKa235KCEbTN2bIXarzbjAtUai15otKpM8wCIAuDwhoMBJUIjtGGtyjAcBiIXuIhoVKq60VmuKhjMatUMZTWth1Oa75dZuH4q1KCTi2DLTvYVFAcVZULAgO+mtTAnVoJmY8oIn7ZWbJqrKhg1LKHDrru6vCABCIduyfD0v4mEmSWr3EjpDfQ-iTKJ0kf4UumexaraDKICACA28kCypAjgEAkHHV1tg0SuAiG2zIddhjdDtLsP4eoYMhWhRkSoeLJm+TQUc6P3vkXJVcAcOeGSUzPNFGKJUVU8fVDZHJ7BuM3dCh9HfjLp-UBtSxU+4YGYNoKET63YJXc6gKEr6pCQa6iEMe4R6UaJ8NRCowBt7EWrlFmLcW3HUHkhoSzRiEvb0YsxNiHEuIuGSKXAr61eIhgYB3cS6xisVFK1GcrUk4AuBQGADuUkNBJb5cZBKsqbkvFXe4aghb0t8rJgNsmw23EYrgdABBA2ptRhm-2CbddFI3My9lli7FDhcUwBCBOu2TC1dwk1lr6R3QmBgLxBgTEFC8QAOyZEyOd4wl2GAgHa71mitEGtoCYptvL+6Lu8UEsYXCmBsK8UONFukz3Xs3aQPdx7H2+V12oCzU6SBlsZbNN9jrKP1u-Zy1tziGgDsJyLuV1IBRGSNea9JZHKO9rUQQPIF+YSxsJWftsFQ2gKgAHlLBsB9atxnTPouxbR--ChgDD4gJcGAnn0v94MGomacXePOtq8S596iaFkhYQKOwBSGu3EE7+7l7bgOXu8QAFZ2D9v0drkueaPWuq9JQqv1c6715hbCRuReM8yybzrDAxxUUJ-9y34OChXbzsAf8bAKjteYNFBYQgADifOEAAE04BBFV6Hvowfkss0Bu8T4WO66e+16LoPn3IuF-D+b4nO2IdMBAPHqMSfiIACEEDRVYjUPPNEzSN+L1Y53W0oYVEr+HavsWdfi-rxti3nECMjfuigTBjQUCcAhNm0imRl-hwAPyaAUNbhQ7BeIABYkfH72kEK3l2cBMFv-f0X2rPvj6MZP46W+zImI98kAD84Ansz8NAKovR7AhZ5In8+dvI4AIB-ZZAIBYDZ8mctcF9a8fcDccJjdPtqASp3YmoqAz8ItA8f8rFqIwAV8W8NB6RpJYcrt4deIABWR7VQPbB+POSnJAanBiE7DuBnT-JnAAWQ1FonEB4GYGACgF+0UAj1Xy4gv0uyvzYHf0yHkgYEwjXykkyBUAD1EIbzD2IgLA-jimRHdAgGE0HgL1MIf1VzACoIy3FzoIB2cGMF4j4iEkezAGMDkhcOoJ728nsEsAf3DiAIRC4gADVAFbDYANAIi9oAoYA2BTZkifArBmB0ihYBtHYXIGVjC6VUjGRSZGBaI90zRhoNBDNijlAMC3EjDP958gjItmi3EiIggKD8c2ixca96jqJG93Co82848E9u8Fhs9SghBh97Ci9kjqI+Qet6i9pC0BshtMjT0YAOc-pGi+UMVRl+w5sLUjiWR9ijEOiWj4RCxlgtj1jBtV0LirFSxditpSxnijFDjlhZtqBvipgEFPi9orj8csC+jItcC-dcIQTOsbjpsoBkiHjNjVilwGA3jjpUSgSfB5t4Fji-iLV4TASH8YTTdITDdoTwSaIbjLUp0JhET+tHjslugsTzUYErUbVLAq0mATi2Ty1bVtAmAWSy0JhK0BS19hSK1xAxSgSSTqCyT8DZTXCBjiizcicAc7dm5MBJJwRMBeJ+DS5o9Xtxiu8RDBjhilD6DDTY8O8Jj2tSgEAHBmBZj89R8HDVifBqBwcoBnA6khQY0eYDMWTWjHCwTHD5T-dKS69VjVTI8ScNTbgtTY82BdT9TVAxibSTTKS59zTm8AcrT29O9E87Txxtg5jXSFj3SaAzR0lMlYpS4xxSUXAX5ewpCiBGtCt2ySsysmChCb9xIUAvCfDhJMh-DWoQBLsAA2cSTgXiCc9JM0IM0M6Mtwi0gHU0lUtlJAEImAMIrY7Ei1Tc34jFQ8pbPc2pAsDYp4s80bP-DAFkyI3faI28-6CWQcBge8vaJmAbH9D8xU6gpc4w4MlU8Mikxwr3ZcmLEYuM+3RMnUvU6GdcwCnMtU0YmPAs204iT9OAWVMssfLYmM5QniXiTAOIMHbgsnI7Lgw7biAEWg3sxClU8Cys-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-L0n0xsHo5iltBJF5FVR6-6bNV+K688+6VlQcbTdJJWvrOW1tCVfofSgiM8oIUW+QcW9qqWzmNJWWvmr1Wkn1RWgG661dBFXpNWpmDJTW5W95W2t+JWltHSr9OVIUfWlQecj87mmgY2301ICW4o82gVS2z28VMFO2xOg1F2xsipN29JFtb1AiEOhcrYz06AMWxJGO4w2xbW6WwFdwfSiu62l8tJe2h2ltQ1HmAFRQJugGlu9OqWTOxJIiDWrup23OrYvOvtFU5C2Mpmo0lmsS1yvkRGbuvRNuqpRJD8+YywOmmiSewi-Mmmue5izcxep21WjOpVde8szexYvG0Egmlo9Kqehggc7wgSYc0czQIG6ibc3cysqItgLiSS8DBI3QLY7I3IngfI++DFOsgscDXKQtMe1Yv8ufG+-8oIxBzXO+lBrBkfO+lyy2VcF8Kgc4YoOIeAEyLSBgPQIAA)

Note that this playground has a ton of errors because I don't have all your types to make it happy. But line 86 that was throwing this error does not have an error now.

---

If you do want to use an array, then you have to make you type take an array.

You have:

```
export type CartProductType = {
  //...
  selectedCustomImage: SelectedCustomImageType;
}
```

And you need to make that an array type. Like this, perhaps:

```
export type CartProductType = {
  //...
  selectedCustomImages: SelectedCustomImageType[];
}
```

Comment: let's assume if I want to use an array. then How should I replace this? `selectedCustomImage: customImage,`

Comment: See my updated answer. And also maybe read the docs on arrays: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays

Comment: I have used ` selectedCustomImage: customImage,`in the use state and`  selectedCustomImage: SelectedCustomImageType[];` and I got this error `Type '{ status: boolean; image: null; price: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'SelectedCustomImageType[]'.
  Type '{ status: boolean; image: null; price: number; }' is not assignable to type 'SelectedCustomImageType'.
    Types of property 'image' are incompatible.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`

Comment: Your `SelectedCustomImageType` type has `image: string` and your value `customImage` has `image: null`. What do you think the problem is? At some point your going to need to learn to read these errors yourself and reason through the problems on your own. That's just coding.